# Only print the integers?

Tags: python

I have this code:

```
for x in range (2,101):
    for y in range (2,101):
        print("{0}/{1}={2}".format(x,y,x/y))
```

It should print the prime numbers from 1 to 100, but it has all the numbers at the end that I want to get rid of. Say for example, 14.895789538953, I don't need/want those extra numbers at the end.

How to change it so it only `print`s the integers?

Comment: What do you mean with "only prints the integers"?

Comment: You can use `floor(x/y)`.

Comment: @alex: I don't think that the aim of the question. Since that would print incorrect results. Probably the OP wants to print only fractions that result in an integer.

Comment: It prints the prime numbers from 1 to 100, but It has all the numbers at the end that I want to get rid of. Say for example, 14.895789538953, I don't need/want those extra numbers at the end.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yes it was only a guess, and I used the right function now :)

Answer (score 2):

Use the [modulo operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) `%` to check for the "remainder" of a division:

```
for x in range (2,101):
    for y in range (2,101):
        if x % y == 0:  # no remainder => x / y is an integer
            print("{0}/{1}={2}".format(x,y,x//y))
```